# how to be able to use C-] with taglist on Vim

Tags: vim, ctags, taglist

I have gVim 7.3 with taglist and ctags 5.8 on windows. Taglist is working nicely (without the need to generate the tags file myself), I can see the tags of the current buffer in the tags window and go to any of them etc.

But I understand that I should be able to use `C-]` in the editor to go to a declaration under the cursor too, this is not working, it keeps saying

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found: myMethod     **strong text**
```

What should I do to be able to use `C-]`

Comment: You might want to use plugin Indexer: http://goo.gl/kixRn . It provides painless automatic tags generation for the whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date. Check my another answer for some details: http://goo.gl/pG9OP

Comment: thanks Dmitry, I will try that for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TagList is a third party plugin completely separated from Vim's `<C-]>` and related commands. Because it doesn't generate a `tags` file or even uses a `tags` file it operates in its own bubble.

`<C-]>` is a native Vim command that uses a `tags` file that you need to generate with a command like `:!ctags -R .` and that you must make sure it is known by Vim.

Comment: understood, thanks. So the question is now, is there a way to tweak taglist to use C-]?

Comment: TagList provides a  list (generated using `ctags`) of the symbols present in your file that you can use to navigate in your code with `<CR>` or a mouse click. `<C-]>` **is totally unrelated to the TagList plugin** and is used to jump to the definition of the symbol under your cursor. Using `<C-]>` in the TagList window makes no sense because there is no code there thus no symbols and no reason to use `ctags` and `<C-]>` there.

Comment: Anyway to extend standard vims tags with TagList? So I can do both navigation via `<cr>` in window and `<c-]>` while cursor on function?

Comment: @FelikZ, you *can* do both already if you have both a tags file *and* TagList running. Ask TagList's authors for that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message means you need to tell VIM where your tags file is.
Try

```
set tags="your file name"
```

you may specify more than one file name, using comma as separator

By the way, another alternative to C-] is g-]. Instead of jumping right away, it shows a list of the different matches.

Comment: but I think taglist plugin does not need to create a tags file...it does it dynamically, and I can navigate to the definitions in the taglist window fine.

Comment: oh sorry. I was too fast. I do not use that plugin, but I checked the documentation, and its has a FAQ section with some troubleshooting.